# Android SSL certificate

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate

android 2.2: for example I have expired ssl certificate, because on my phone system time is incorrect. How I can to set time from worldclock.com for checking the certificate? without changing time on my phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't and that is the point. If everybody did certificate validation based on their own time, it wouldn't be too reliable. Just set the correct time to your phone.